# how to get specific key value from a hashmap using freemarker template

Tags: java, json, hashmap, freemarker

below is the main function where i am putting some key values into a hashmap.

how to structure the freemarker template so that it reads just one key value and not iterate through the whole list

```
import freemarker.template.TemplateException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws  TemplateException {
        HashMap<String, String> gtmData = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Map gtm = new HashMap();
        gtmData.put("Uid", "a12");
        gtmData.put("SettlementCurrency","USD");
        gtmData.put("Quantity","123455");
        Map root = new HashMap();
        root.put("hello", gtmData);

        FreeMarkerConverter convert = new FreeMarkerConverter();
        try {
            convert.setTemplateName("gtm-temp-h");
            convert.convert(root);
        }

        catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the freemarker template where in place of root.SettlementCurrency i want the value of that key, but every example showed printing the whole list

```
"header"[
{
messageid :$(root.uid)
SettlementCurrency:$(root.SettlementCurrency)

}
```

]

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully follow your example, but in my FreeMarker Templates, I use notation of `Map[key]`.

**Creating Map**

```
Map<String, String> ringImageLocationMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Ring ringItem : ringItems){
    String url = getRingImageUrl(ringItem);
    ringImageLocationMap.put(ringItem.getIoItemGuid(), url);
}
```

**Java adding a Map to the model:**

```
model.put("ringImageLocationMap", orderSummary.getRingImageLocationMap());
```

**Freemarker accessing the Map**

```
<#if (ringImageLocationMap[item.ioItemGuid])??> 
    <#assign location = ringImageLocationMap[item.ioItemGuid]>                                              
    <td colspan="4" style="padding-top: 100px; padding-bottom: 130px;">
        <img id="productImage" src="${location}" width="259"/>
    </td>
<#else>
    <td colspan="4" style="padding-top: 100px; padding-bottom: 130px;">
        &nbsp;
    </td>
</#if>
```